# How to set a maximum where value=$sum

Tags: php

I have an option for users to give away point to other users

I would like to make sure that the points they give away don't exceed the points they have.

How do I do this?

maxvalue doesn't work.

```
<?php
$user=$_SESSION['SESS_USERID'];
if(isset($_REQUEST['user'])){
$user = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_GET['user']);
}

$sql=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT SUM(sterren) AS total FROM sterren WHERE userid='$user'");

if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($sql)){
$sum = $row['total'];

if ($row["total"] >= '1') {

echo"
<table>
<some form action>
///Some more code to select the user to give the points to
<input type='text' name='sterren' id='sterren' size='3' maxlength='3' maxvalue=$sum ></td>
</form>
</table>";
}
}
<?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use the 'number' attribute instead of 'text'.

Your syntax should be something like this:

```
<input type='number' name='sterren' id='sterren' min='0' max='<?php echo $sum;?>'>
```

Comment: You can set a min attribute to 0 like this: <input type='number' name='sterren' id='sterren' maxval='<?php echo $sum;?>' min='0'>

Comment: Solved: <input type='number' name='sterren' id='sterren' max=".$sum." min=0 > Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think the synatx should be like the following

```
<input type='text' name='sterren' id='sterren' size='3' min="1" max="5">
```

Try **max** instead of **maxvalue** as the input attribute

References: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_max.asp

Demo: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_max_min

Comment: how does that answer the question?

Comment: This helped me with the max and min issue, so it is sort of an answer